# Calculate the mean of specific sections of a 3D array

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, 3d, aggregate

I have a 3D array of temperatures with the shapes 31, 400, 600 for date/time, latitude and longitude. I want to work out the monthly mean temperature for each latitude and longitude point in the array. For example I have tried the following:

```
longitude = (temperature[0:0:,:0])
print(longitude.shape)
meanlongitude = np.mean(longitude)
print(meanlongitude)

(0, 0, 600)
nan
```

I am unsure as to how to aggregate this data properly.

Comment: just do temperature.mean(axis=0), is that what you're looking for? It'll return a 400x600 array, averaged over 31 days.

Comment: im essentially looking to create two lists, one with the average temperature value from across the month for each latitude point, and one with the average temperature value from across the month for each longitude point.

Comment: Assuming temperature is an array of shape 31x400x600 (daysxlatxlong), you get the mean for each latitude by temperature.mean(axis=(0,2)). Similarly, longitude wise mean can be found by temperature.mean(axis=(0,1)).

Comment: Latitudes and longitudes aren't points per se; 1 latitude is actually a slice of 600 longitudes at a point, so a single latitude has the shape (1x600). Similarly, a longitude is a slice along all latitudes, so it's shape is (1,400). If you want to get the mean across a latitude, say, then first you calculate the mean over 31 days. Then you calculate the mean over all the 600 longitude points present in that latitude. So you simply call mean with two axis as inputs.